# delete some list in 2 diensional list

Tags: python

I Have A 2 Dimensional List Like This ::

```
My_List = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
```

I Want To Delete 3 Last of My_List And Have Outcome Like This ::

```
Outcome =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

And My Code Is This::

```
Outcome = My_List.pop(-3)
```

And This Remove The List By Index -3 And Not Delete The 3 Last List.

Can Anyone Help Me????!!!!

Comment: I think instead you can just do `Outcome = My_List[:-3]`

Comment: a basic suggestion, name the variables like `an_apple`, which is more python. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
My_List = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
Outcome = My_List[:-3]
print(Outcome)

>>> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

My_List[:-3] is the same as My_List[0:-3], and its the same as My_List[0:3]

Answer (score 1):

Just slice it.

```
Outcome=My_List[:-3]
```